# Reload all data points on c3.js graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, c3.js

I made a simple `div` in html:

```
<div class='all'>
    Show all
</div>
```

Here's the JS I tagged along to it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.all').click(function(){
        chart.flush();
    });
});
```

When a user clicks on the various x data set names in the legend, the data points will disappear. I want it so that if they click, say 20 data point names, all they will need is a single click of a button to put them all back on the graph instead of having to reclick all 20 options again.

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on the div class `all`, the chart will reload all of the data points there.

Like-wise, I also want it so that I can remove all data points.

In the c3.js reference guide for flush (http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-flush), I thought that this would reload all of the points on the graph. Apparently it doesn't. Is there a way so that once I click the div, all the points will be placed back onto the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do `chart.show();` instead of `chart.flush();`?

To hide all data you can then do `chart.hide()`.

`chart.toggle()` can do the trick too, it will show the hidden data and hide the displayed ones.

Comment: @John : Did my answer help you in any way ?